# telnet refusing traffic on arbitrary port over network in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, remote-access, localhost, telnet

I have written a python script to listen on port 2626 and executed the script.

*proof that localhost is listening*

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2626          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I can connect via telnet to this port over localhost with the following command:

```
:~$ telnet localhost 2626
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

However when I try to connect from a remote machine the connection gets refused.

```
 :~$ telnet 128.251.xxx.xxx 2626
 Trying 128.251.xxx.xxx...
 telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I even issued the following command to accept traffic on port 2626:

```
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 2626 -j ACCEPT
```

What could be the reason telnet on port 2626 is refusing connections from remote machines and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `127.0.0.1:2626` from the netstat output indicates that your python script is only accepting connections on `127.0.0.1`. If you wish to be able to accept connections from any address, have it accept connections on `0.0.0.0`

Comment: thank you! you both had the right answer! award going to first response.

Answer (score 7):

That output shows that your program is listening on `127.0.0.1` only. Listening sockets (open ports) are either bound to a specific interface, as in this case, or to all interfaces (in which case you'll see `0.0.0.0` as a notation for 'any address'). The implications of binding to `127.0.0.1` only are that only connections through that interface will go to the listening socket, and hence your program. If you're using python's `socket` library, either bind to your external IP in the `bind()` call, or bind to all IPs, something like this:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> s.bind(('', 6666))
>>> s.listen(1)
```

which gives the result you want from netstat

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

and indeed can be connected to from another machine

```
ial@roach> telnet polihale 6666
Trying 128.243.20.139...
Connected to polihale.
Escape character is '^]'.
```